# Reference request: Analysis, Algebra and Topology - Same author(s)/publisher(s), progressive order

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, analysis, reference-request

Is there anywhere I can acquire a collection of all Mathematical undergraduate textbooks by the same publishing author, or authors(so that they are similarly written) and can be completed in a logical order.

I feel as though this would remove any issues in regards to prerequisite knowledge, as I would know everything required for progression to the next topic.

I don't care for statistics, but I would like textbooks/notes for Analysis, Topology and Algebra.

Pdf form provided legally by the author is very much preferred.

Perhaps no author(s)/publisher(s) have ever done this, perhaps no-one knows the three fields sufficiently to do such. Thank you for your time.

Note: I am $14$ and live on my own, I am unlikely to be able to afford numerous textbooks.

Comment: You sound like a really interesting person. Unfortunately, I dont know of any such series of books. There are however many lists on this site giving suggested books on these topics you might have to explore a little to finds ones that are right for you. You can also find many electronic math and science books online from http://lib.freescienceengineering.org/

Comment: You might be able to sign up for borrowing privileges at a university library for a couple hundred dollars a year. Even if you don't do this, most university libraries allow members of the public in-person access to their collections. So that way you can check out any books you might want to buy beforehand. Alternatively, your local library might be able to get books for you by interlibrary loan.

Comment: By now it should be possible to learn undergraduate and much of graduate mathematics from lecture notes posted freely on the web by their authors (e.g., getting the basics of algebra from Hefferon's and Judson's books and then googling one's way up in the directions one is interested in). Having them written by the same author is not a condition I would filter for; this happens rarely enough and doesn't necessarily correlate with quality, which is more important.

Comment: It's not exactly what you were asking for, but you might be interested in MIT's [OpenCourseWare program](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/find-by-number/). (Mathematics is Course 18 there.) There are extensive notes there on everything from introductory calculus to grad-level seminars, and you can look for particular professors' notes if you like their style. (I'd particularly recommend Victor Guillemin's notes; he's a great lecturer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which authors cover all 3, but you may try books of Rudin and Serge Lang.

Rudin is more about analysis, but he also equips you necessary topology to go further (try his Principles of Mathematical analysis, where he introduces topology first, and then go to other topics in analysis, I find it very pedagogical). However his writing is very concise and quite often, not easy to understand. Here are his 3 most famous books:
- Principles of mathematical analysis.
- Real and complex analysis.
- Functional analysis.

Serge Lang has many books (mostly in algebra, as he is more about algebra), and his writing is easy to understand. You may try some following books:
- Undergraduate analysis.
- Undergraduate algebra.
- Linear algebra.

Personally, I find Serge Lang is more appropriate for basic undergraduate level, whereas Rudin is better for an advanced one. For downloading, just google.

Comment: I have only bad experiences with Lang's "Algebra". I think it is very good in their choice of topics, but its dense and unpolished writing makes them hard to learn from.